# Temperature gauge messing up

Tags: ford, gauges

I was driving earlier and my truck stalled. I noticed before I stalled  my temperature gauge wasn’t were it should have been. I started driving home and my temperature went up a little bit when I went to reverse into my driveway my temperature gauge shot down below the cold start temp. I’m at a loss and need help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!